# Open source IDEs released under GPL

Tags: licensing

Some IDEs (or code editors like Notepad++) are released under GPL. If I decide to make a program using the IDE, do I have to release my program under the GPL? Or is it only if I take code from the open source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you would not. See the [GPL FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#CanIUseGPLToolsForNF).

> **Can I use GPL-covered editors such as GNU Emacs to develop non-free
>   programs? Can I use GPL-covered tools
>   such as GCC to compile them?**
>
> Yes, because the copyright on the
>   editors and tools does not cover the
>   code you write. Using them does not
>   place any restrictions, legally, on
>   the license you use for your code.
>
> Some programs copy parts of themselves
>   into the output for technical
>   reasons—for example, Bison copies a
>   standard parser program into its
>   output file. In such cases, the copied
>   text in the output is covered by the
>   same license that covers it in the
>   source code. Meanwhile, the part of
>   the output which is derived from the
>   program's input inherits the copyright
>   status of the input.
>
> As it happens, Bison can also be used
>   to develop non-free programs. This is
>   because we decided to explicitly
>   permit the use of the Bison standard
>   parser program in Bison output files
>   without restriction. We made the
>   decision because there were other
>   tools comparable to Bison which
>   already permitted use for non-free
>   programs.

Comment: @TheLQ .-. why?

Comment: @Crazy Eddie - answers should be selfstanding, making them usable in printouts.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're free to use the tool for its intended purpose.  Only if you use part of its *code* are you bound by its license.